# Truncated Comment Preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

[image: Truncated Comment]

As I'm about to reply with a comment, the text field is cut off until I swipe left or right.

iPhone 5 iOS 7.0.6

App: 0.1.54

Comment: Yup. Doing it to me as I type this! Seems to think the screen is 20 pixels wider than it actually is or something. But not all the time.

Comment: I'm looking into this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

Fixed in version **0.1.57**