# Comments box shifted off screen

Tags: bug, ios-app

Noticed this earlier today when commenting on a post the box is shifted off to the left, Image 1.
You can then swipe the box back into view, Image 2.
<s>I don't believe that no one else has noticed this, so maybe its just me?</s>

iPhone 5S - iOS 7.0.4

**Image 1**

[image: Comment box shifted left]

**Image 2**

[image: Comment box swiped back into view]

Comment: I can reproduce this problem on iPhone 5s, iOS 7.1.1.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229993/259198